# Change the names of module level exports

Tags: javascript, webpack

Can Webpack, when minifying JavaScript, change the names of the module level export symbols and also all their references wherever they are used?

For e.g.

**lib.js**

```
export function foo() { }
```

**index.js**

```
import * as lib from "./lib.js";

lib.foo();
```

Presently, the name `foo` and therefore all its references where it is used, are left in-tact, that is, they are not obfuscated by Webpack as it is a module level export.

At present, Webpack only minifies private functions within modules or everything that's not in an ES 6 module.

Is there a way that Webpack can be told to obscure these as well?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-obfuscator

Comment: Thank you. I will try out what it does and mark your answer in a day or two.